# Close/reopen TraceListener created with XML config, pointing to external USB stick

Tags: c#, .net, logging, trace, tracelistener

I have a `TraceListener` object, used for logging, created in app.config that points to a location on a USB stick.

I'm getting an `IOException` with the message

> The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.

when attempting to `Trace.WriteLine()` after I've removed the device then plugged it back in. I understand that it's happening because the handle to the open file that the Trace listener has is invalidated when I unplug it.

I've managed to thwart the `IOException`s by calling `Close()` on the TraceListener, but I can't figure out how to re-open the handle to that same file again. The MSDN documentation for `TextWriterTraceListener.Close()` method says

> Calling a Write or WriteLine method after calling Close automatically
>   reopens the stream.

But it just isn't doing it. I'm not getting further output after I close the stream.

**EDIT:**

Some more information

I've found that the Trace Listener is only unable to write again if, after I call `Close()`, I attempt to write while the drive is unplugged. If I don't write while the drive is unplugged then plug the drive again and try to write, everything works fine. I've also verified that my `Trace.Listeners` collection still contains my listener.

Comment: Looking at the internals of TextWriterTraceListener it appears that the internal method `EnsureWriter` clears the filename if creation of the stream fails and returns false which makes the writeline method a no-op. Subsequent calls to EnsureWriter checks first if filename is empty and if so, skip the creation of the stream. I'm afraid you have to create your own writer that does handle the removal and reappearance of devices more gracefully.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I did find the `Trace.Refresh()` method on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) which I've been testing with success for the past few hours. I'm not 100% sure if it's the solution I want, but it looks promising.

Comment: Hmmm, that basically reinitializes the complete diagnostics framework. It does clear the listeners, tracessource etc and recreates them so that will work...

Comment: I haven't seen the source for it, but I do know that we only initialize that one listener in the application's config. It did seem a bit heavy to me when I read about it. I'm pushing for just a re-write of this logging framework anyway. It wasn't done anywhere near properly. I guess refresh will have to do for now

Comment: Make your current way out an answer. It is at least not something I considered possible. If I can find an hour somewhere I'll whip together a TraceListener that handles your case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found after a bunch of research that `Trace.Refresh()` seems to solve this problem but, from  reading the original question's comments from rene, this method will re-initialize the entire Trace framework. It seems a bit heavy for what I wanted, but maybe this answer will help someone else.

[`Trace.Refresh()` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.refresh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Remarks from MSDN:

> Trace configuration data is captured when the application is started.
>   If the configuration data is changed after the application is started,
>   call the Refresh method to update the trace configuration data.